# QGIS Python - Exporting Map Layout to PDF and PNG

Tags: pyqgis

I have created Python script to export my layouts to PDF (where is select folder location to save) and PNG (to a defined location), but i am getting a error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
> NameError: name 'result' is not defined
> ```

I have tried this previously and it worked fine, but am unable to find the error:

```
project = QgsProject().instance()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
prj = QgsProject.instance()

#Refresh Overview Layout
print(result, 'In progress.......')
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Tree Condition Plan')

map_item = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemMap)][0]
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())

#Tree Plan export to PDF to user selected folder

fileNamePDFplan = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save Tree Plan as PDF', 'C:\\Users\\MatthewWhitehead\\OneDrive - Innovative Forestry Ltd\\Clients\\', filter='*.pdf')
if fileNamePDFplan:
    png_pathPDFplan = fileNamePDFplan[0]
    
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()

result = exporter.exportToPdf(png_pathPDFplan, settings)
print(result, 'Well done we have saved the PDF of Tree Plan')

#Tree Plan export image to specific folder
print(result, 'In progress.......')
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage('C:\\Users\\MatthewWhitehead\\OneDrive - Innovative Forestry Ltd\\Arboricultural Reports\\Tree Condition Survey\\Tree Condition Plan.png',
         QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
         
print(result, 'Well done we have updated Tree Plan image')

#Refresh Overview Layout
print(result, 'In progress.......')

layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Tree Condition Overview')

map_item = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemMap)][0]
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())

#Overview export to PDF to user selected folder

fileNamePDFOver = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save Overview as PDF', 'C:\\Users\\MatthewWhitehead\\OneDrive - Innovative Forestry Ltd\\Clients\\', filter='*.pdf')
if fileNamePDFOver:
    png_pathPDFOver = fileNamePDFOver[0]
    
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()

result = exporter.exportToPdf(png_pathPDFOver, settings)
print(result, 'Well done we have saved the PDF of Overview')

#Overview export image to specific folder
print(result, 'In progress.......')

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage('C:\\Users\\MatthewWhitehead\\OneDrive - Innovative Forestry Ltd\\Arboricultural Reports\\Tree Condition Survey\\Tree Condition Overview.png',
         QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
         
print(result, 'Well done we have updated Overview image')
```

Comment: Just remove line 6 -> `print(result, 'In progress.......')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've copied a print line around at some point in debugging and you've accidentally put one before you set result.

See where you have the print line before result is set:

[image: screenshot of code error]

Comment: Ahh yes, i have now added 'Result = 0' and it works, thanks for the help.